# making game in pad and iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Respected sir,
I need help .

If I want to make the object move only when the key(button) is pressed. what should I do to shift the position of the object on frames where the key is held down:- 
If I pressed left or right button the object should move on that side .

thanks in advance .

Comment: What object? There is no context for your question. Please rephrase and clarify with code if possible. Your question is currently unanswerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though you are quite early in the process of making a game on the platform. 
A lot of the basics would be covered in a book on the subject which will take you through the steps one at a time.
A good such book is "Beginning iPhone Games Development" available from Amazon.

Alternatively you could have a look at the code examples Apple provides. 
The [Move Me](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html) example is a good starting point as it shows both user interaction and the movement of objects.

Good luck and, above all, enjoy.

Teo

Answer (score 0):

There is a fantastic page with tutorials from Mike and I guess you will find an answer there.
http://www.71squared.com/iphone-tutorials/